# Am I able to add a page break between two subreports in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, pagination, ssrs-tablix, subreport

I have an SSRS report with a tablix containing five subreports. I am trying to get it to the first page for each of the top four subreports on one page in the main report and then the first page of the comments subreport on the second page. Then, it continues this with pages three and four of the main report, etc because the data is linked together across the subreports.

[image]

Below is the current output. I tried putting Comments into a rectangle with a page break before it, but this breaks the link. It displays pages from the top 4 subreports and then displays the comments pages.

Is there a way to add a page break between two subreports?
Sorry about previous ambiguity.

[image]

Comment: just add a thin rectangle at the point you want to force the page break. You can set page break properties on the rectangle.

Comment: I don't understand. I can't have the top 4 in a rectangle and the comments outside of it while keeping all the data linked together across the subreports. I tried just now to add a rectangle between subreport4 and comments with a page break after the rectangle, but that did not work.

Comment: I don't understand what you want then. Edit your post and show what you get now and what you want to achieve. The question asks how to put a page break between 2 sub reports, and what I said does exactly that so there must be something you haven't made clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the "Add a page break before" box in the Comments subreport tablix. This seemed to work. I figured I would need to do something in the main report, but I'll take what I can get.